# Libgdx 2d floor Animation

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm building Runner Game.
 Ground Class.

```
public class Ground extends Actor {

private Texture texture;
private ArrayList<Vector2> groundLocations;
private float speed;
private float cameraLeft, cameraRight;
private int textureWidth;


public Ground() {
    this.cameraRight = Const.GAME_WIDTH + Const.GAME_MARGIN;
    this.cameraLeft = 0 - Const.GAME_MARGIN;
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ui/ground.png"));
    groundLocations = new ArrayList<Vector2>();
    init();
}

public void setSpeed(float speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
}

private void init() {

    textureWidth = texture.getWidth();
    float currentPosition = cameraLeft;
    while (currentPosition < cameraRight) {

        Vector2 newLocation = new Vector2(currentPosition, 0);
        groundLocations.add(newLocation);
        currentPosition += textureWidth;
    }

}

public int getFloorHeight() {
    return texture.getHeight();
}


@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);
    int size = groundLocations.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Vector2 location = groundLocations.get(i);
        location.x -= delta * speed;
        if (location.x < cameraLeft) {

            location.x = findMax().x + textureWidth;
        }
    }

}

private Vector2 findMax() {
    return Collections.max(groundLocations, new Vector2Comparator());
}


@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    for (Vector2 location : groundLocations) {
        batch.draw(texture, location.x, location.y);
    }
}




public void dispose() {
    if (texture != null)
        texture.dispose();
}
```

}

- Ground Texture is 128x128
- GAME_WIDTH = 1024f
- GAME_MARGIN = 250f
- speed = changes.

While the ground is moving according to Speed and FPS. (Speed * delta)
Problem is : There are always Gaps between ground Textures. after certain Movement
function findMax finds the texture with the biggest X 
any help would be Appreciated.

Update : Images
[image: Image 1]

Comment: What do you mean gaps between ground textures? Could we see an image of  the problem?

Comment: Update Added Images..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOW Simply Solution cant believe i didn't see it.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    Vector2 location = groundLocations.get(i);
    if (location.x < cameraLeft) {

        location.x = findMax().x + textureWidth;
    }          
    location.x -= delta * speed;

}
```